# May one ask a non-jew to register for an event online on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, gentiles

Let's say there was a registration form for an event online. The form opens during the day on Shabbat. It is highly likely (almost undoubtedly the case) that by the time Shabbat is over, the event's registration will be full, and it will be too late. May one ask a non jew prior to Shabbat to register one for the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SA OC 307.5

> דבר שאינו מלאכה ואינו אסור לעשותו בשבת אלא משום שבות מותר לישראל לומר לאינו יהודי לעשותו בשבת **והוא שיהיה שם מקצת חולי או יהיה צריך לדבר צורך הרבה או מפני מצוה** כיצד אומר ישראל לאינו יהודי בשבת לעלות באילן להביא שופר לתקוע תקיעת מצוה או להביא מים דרך חצר שלא עירבו לרחוץ בו המצטער ויש אוסרין:     הגה: ולקמן סימן תקפ"ו (סעיף כב) פסק להתיר ועיין לעיל סימן רע"ו דיש מקילין אפילו במלאכה דאורייתא ועיין שם סעיף ג':&rlml;

It's allowed to say to a non Jew to make something that is not a Melacha Deorayta on Shabbat... but only if it is linked to a problem of illness or a great need. ...

In sayif 4

> מותר לתת לאינו יהודי מעות מערב שבת לקנות לו ובלבד שלא יאמר לו קנה בשבת: ‏

It's permitted to say erev Shabbat a non Jew to buy something, but they don't not say explicitely to buy it on Shabbat.

In sayif 3

> אסור ליתן לאינו יהודי מעות מערב שבת לקנות לו בשבת אבל יכול לומר לו קנה לעצמך ואם אצטרך אקנה ממך לאחר השבת: ‏

It's prohibited to give to a non Jew money Erev Shabbat to buy something on Shabbat but thwy can say him buy it for yourself and if I will need it I will buy it from you after Shabbat.

So, apparently, to say on Shabbat it's a problem and it is prohibited. But if they ask him before Shabbat following the ways indicated in Sayif 3 and 4, it's allowed. But if your name must to be written in the registration may be a problem. I think that the NJ can buy two places with his name and he can sell one of them.

Answer (score 4):

It is prohibited to ask a non-Jew to do a *melacha* for you. It makes no difference whether the request is made before or during Shabbos. (For overview of the relevant Halachos, see [here](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Amirah_LeNochri#cite_note-2).)